# Approximating a binary-multi-variable-polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, optimization, approximation, binary, approximation-theory

Let $$F(x_1,\dots,x_k) = \sum_{l_1 + \dots + l_k = n} C_{l_1,\dots,l_n}x_1^{l_1} x_2^{l_2} \dots x_k^{l_k}$$

Now all $x_i \in \{0,1\}$, i.e they are binary variables, I need to find or approximate all the coefficients $C_{l_1,\dots,l_n}$(these coefficients are known to be whole numbers)  I can sample the value of $F(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ at various points, but finding its value at points where the majority of $x_i's$ are zero is much more computationally efficient than points where a large number of $x_i's $ are ones.

Can anyone point me in the direction to solving it? I am clueless about the literature on methods that exist for such approximations.

Also, feel free to reply if you know a method to approximate such functions but using a different functional form.

Comment: Because $x_i^{l_i}=x_i$ if $l_i>0$, you cannot distinguish coefficients that have the same sparsity pattern of $l$.

Comment: I agree, does it mean its impossible because indeed $x_1^2 \cdot x_2$ and $x_2^2 \cdot x_1$ are indistinguishable for a given value of $x_1$ and $x_2$

Comment: Yes, you can evaluate $F$ at all $x\in\{0,1\}^k$ and still not be able to determine $C$.

Comment: And what if we change the functional form of approximation ?

Comment: You can completely determine the coefficients for $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k C_i x_i$ with $k$ evaluations.

Comment: I should have said it, but I know that the polynomial I am approximating has a degree n, infact all its monomials are of degree n like in the functional form of approximation

Comment: How do you evaluate $F$ for a given $x$?